# How to initialize empty array of objects in vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using Vue3 with Nuxt. I want to initialize an empty array of objects, and then set it.

```
let results = ref([]);
        results.value = [
            {
                "name": input.value,
            }
        ]
```

However I am getting an error
`Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

I tried this

```
let results: any[] = ref([]);
```

And looked at v-for documentation in vue. But the example initializes a non-empty array of objects

```
const items = ref([
                 { 
                   message: 'Foo' 
                 }, 
                 { 
                    message: 'Bar' 
                 }
])
```

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for

Comment: ref doesn't return an array, so this is incorrect type. As many functions of this kind, it's a generic, like ref<Whatever[])([])

Comment: What do you mean by ref doesn't return an array? Please elaborate, as the example on vue documentation const items = ref([{ message: 'Foo' }, { message: 'Bar' }]) is clearly making ref returning an array.

Comment: Ref is an object with "value" key. You can use refs without "value" in templates due to ref unwrapping, which is documented

Comment: @GhassanBarghouti how your `input` is defined? I would say the type issue comes from there, not from your ref array itself.

Comment: @Ellrohir input.value is a normal string. It could be just "John" so everything will be results.value = [
            {
                "name": "Ghassan"
            }
        ]

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing the empty array just fine. The error is from typescript, which is a distinctly different kind of error than the functionality related question being asked. The actual question should be "how do I type a ref array of objects?", the answer is with the `Ref` type, which is [documented here](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-ref)

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import type { Ref } from 'vue'

const results: Ref<object[]> = ref([])
```

alternative syntax:

```
const results = ref<object[]>([])
```

It would be better if it was a typed object, but that is up to you to decide.